Polynomials splitting in normal extensions
I was studying field theory when a question came to my mind.
It is known that a normal extension L/K may be characterised as a splitting field of a set S of non-constant polynomials with coefficients in K or, equivalently, as an extension such that every irreducible polynomial with coefficients in K having a root in L splits over L.
My question is the following: given a normal extension L/K, is there a characterisation of the irreducible polynomials in K having a root in L (and, therefore, splitting over L)?
For example, the irreducible (in K) polynomials dividing the elements of a set S as above certainly split (one can, in general, substitute S with the set of irreducible polynomials dividing some element of S), but they and their products are certainly not the only ones splitting: for example, over the complex numbers all real polynomials split, not only the multiples of the minimal polynomial of i over R.
EDIT In light of an observation below, I have added the irreducibility hypothesis.

A polynomial in $K[x]$ splits in $L$ if and only if it is a product of minimal polynomials of some elements of $L$. Not sure you can get something better than that. if $L$ is algebraically closed, indeed any polynomial of $K[x]$ will satisfy that condition.

@Mark Therefore, in other words, a polynomial over K splits over L if and only if every its irreducible divisor (in K) has a root in L. Not much but still something. Thank you.

@Mark The question then boils out to irreducibles over K, as in my updated question.
